# Can't delete custom SharePoint webpart DLL

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts

I've created a couple of custom web parts and put the DLLs in the /bin folder for testing. I now want to delete the DLLs from the /bin folder but I keep getting the following error:

Cannot delete xxxxx: Access is Denied
Make sure the disk is not full or write-protected and that the file is not currently in use.

I can rename the DLL files, so they arent completely locked, however if I do I get the error
Could not load file or assembly 'xxxxxx' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040) displayed in the browser when load the site.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Charlie

Answer (score 3):

They are probably locked by IIS. Try this:
iisreset /stop
(delete them)
iisreset /start

Answer (score 1):

open windows task manager. end the process named 'cisv'. that worked for me.